# How to enable multiple host names / IP Addresses with mailcow-dockerized mail server

Tags: docker, email, postfix-mta

I have previously setup my mailcow server for my domain `domain1.com`, and setup mail for it and another domain `domain2.com`. And both domains can successfully send emails by using the same MX `mail.domain1.com`

`domain1.com` has `A` record `mail` pointing to `IP1`

MailCow's hostname is `mail.domain1`

I recently acquired another IP address `IP2` for the same server, and was hoping to use `mail.domain2.com` as a hostname for `domain2`

I changed the MX record for `domain2.com` to become `mail.domain2.com` and added `A` record `mail` pointing to `IP2`, Additionally, I added `mail.domain2.com` to mailcow.conf's ADDITIONAL_SAN, restarted mailcow using `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -g`

But still, all emails sent from `email@domain2.com` using the SOGO email client are received with header still showing the previous hostname and IP. (`mail.domain1.com` and `IP1`)

Even SMTP replies with `EHLO mail.domain1.com`

I want the header to originate from `mail.domain2.com` and `IP2` when sending from emails `@domain2.com` ,and `mail.domain1.com` and `IP1` when sending from emails `@domain1.com`

Is this possible to configure?

Update:

I went to mailcow UI -> Configuration-> Mail Setup,
Clicked on the "DNS" Action of `domain2.com` and found out that they were not updated (MX is still `mail.domain1.com` and the A record `mail` still points to `IP1`)

But on my server, querying `dig mail.domain2.com` shows the A record `mail` pointing to `IP2`

And querying the dns cache of unbound using `docker-compose exec unbound-mailcow unbound-control dump_cache >~/unbound.cache` outputs the correct updated info (`IP2`)

How do i trigger a dns update in mailcow-dockerized ?